# #1366 - Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' for column 'cid' at row 1

Tags: mysql, mybb

I have installed MyBB local using XAMPP and it goes smoothly. But when I do it on the server it give me errors.

MyBB creates and inserts a lot of data by itself and I found out the errors are in queries like:

```
INSERT INTO... VALUES ('NULL', ...)
```

On my localhost MySQL (which is 5.5.27 for both) accepts this kind of query, where 'NULL' is passed as a String. But in the server it gives an error #1366 as the title says.

The problem is that changing the query is not an option since it is A LOT of queries, so anyone has an idea where I can configure this to work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i know about mysql that when i restore backup generated from some different version then it has some syntax difference like you have. but there is option while restoring i.e. 'ignore errors' like something

Comment: Actually Im not exporting the database, Im installing a fresh version of MyBB on the server and this errors appears while Im using it (installing plugins, etc...)

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that for MySQL (in this case) **`'NULL'` is not the same as `NULL`**.

Due to the fact that the column is expecting numeric data your statement does not work while the following would work:

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES (NULL, ...)
```

... maybe you can change [the MySQL mode the server is running on](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html).

Answer (score 8):

I think your MySQL Server is running in strict mode.

This can be fixed in one of two ways, but you may have to get your hosting company to do this for you.

**Method 1:**
Open the "my.ini" file within the MySQL installation directory and look for something like...

```
# Set the SQL mode to strict
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Replace with:

```
# Set the SQL mode to strict
sql-mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

**Method 2:**

You may be able to run an SQL query within your database management tool such as phpMyAdmin which can normally be found from your web hosting control panel:

```
SET @@global.sql_mode= '';
```