# Can't insert None into mysql int field

Tags: mysql, pymysql

I need to insert an int or None into a MySql int field (which is nullable). 
This is my code:

```
cur = db.cursor()
contents = [None, 3]
for element in contents:
    print(element)
    cur.execute('insert into test.new_test (blubb) values (%s)', element)
db.commit()
```

When I don't use None, but another int, this works. I just don't understand, why None does not work, I get the error

> pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1"),

despite all of the solutions that I found for this saying that %s is able to handle None...
Also, is there maybe a way to add the entire list at once (a new row for each entry) without using a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mysql it should be NULL so you need to change it to:

```
cur = db.cursor()
contents = ['NULL', 3]
for element in contents:
    print(element)
    cur.execute('insert into test.new_test (blubb) values (%s)', element)
db.commit()
```

**EDIT**

To solve the new isue you can change it to:

```
cur = db.cursor()
contents = [None, 3]
for element in contents:
    print(element)
    if element==None:
        cur.execute('insert into test.new_test (blubb) values (NULL)')
    else:
        cur.execute('insert into test.new_test (blubb) values (%s)', element)
db.commit()
```

Another way is to change the strict mode like it explains [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469720/1366-incorrect-integer-value-null-for-column-cid-at-row-1)

Comment: if I do that, I get `pymysql.err.InternalError: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' for column 'blubb' at row 1")`

Comment: Contents = ['',3]?

Comment: pymysql.err.InternalError: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'blubb' at row 1")

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the NONE by NULL. The command delivered to the MySQL server should looks like:

```
insert into test.new_test (blubb) values (NULL)
```

Where blubb is a valid column in the table new_test, and, must be allowed NULL values.

Cheers,

Comment: How would I do that? If I try to exchange None for 'Null' or '', I get an error... (See other answer)